# Extension Builder Frontend plugin showing Extbase object error

Tags: typo3

I created an extension using Extension builder called "Events". Also created a frontend plugin. The model created has attributes `eventDate` and `eventtitle`. The controller has the actions : `Show, List, and New.`

I added this plugin to a page. But it does not seem to be working.

Its showing me an error at :  `$events = $this->eventRepository->findAll();` in the `EventController`.

The php logs show me the following error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function findAll() on a non-object in ../typo3conf/ext/event/Classes/Controller/EventController.php on line 44`

The appache logs show me the follwoing error :

```
Thu May 09 19:19:26 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP  30. TYPO3\\Event\\Controller\\EventController->listAction() /home/Public/Project/typo3/typo3_src-6.1.0/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Controller/ActionController.php:277, referer: http://localhost/Project/typo3/typo3/mod.php?M=web_ViewpageView&id=74
```

How do I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check if `eventRepository` is correctly injected. Check the option "is aggregate root" under "Domain object settings" of the model in the extension builder and check if the file `yourext/Classes/Domain/Repository/EventRepository.php` has been created. Clearing the cache in backend is required!

The repository need to be injected by either

TYPO3 Version < 6.0

```
/**
 * @var Tx_YourExt_Domain_Repository_EventRepository
 */
protected $eventRepository;

/**
 * injectEventRepository
 *
 * @param Tx_YourExt_Domain_Repository_EventRepository $eventRepository
 * @return void
 */
public function injectEventRepository(Tx_YourExt_Domain_Repository_EventRepository $eventRepository) {
    $this->eventRepository = $eventRepository;
}
```

or TYPO3 Version >= 6.0

```php
/**
 * eventRepository
 *
 * @var \YourVendor\YourExtension\Domain\Repository\EventRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $eventRepository;
```

Comment: Well, I forgot to update my code. The error got rectified. And yes, the answer you gave was the solution. Thank You. 

However, myext repository extends `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository`. So in my `myext/domain/repository/mextrepository.php` do I need to add `findAll()` function ... my `extbase/persistance/repository.php` is having a `findAll`function..wont that be automatically inherited here?

Comment: Sometimes, just using the @inject stuff on a 6.2 LTS installation won't work. There got to be more to it, than just adding that protected variable.

Answer (score 0):

remember to login logout as well.
sometimes changes won't propagate until you login/logout 
or disable/enable the extension.